# to return True when the post has a like from the creator of the post

Tags: django, django-queryset

to return True when the post has a like from the creator of the post
how to make such an analog on django

```
user = {
    'id': 121
}

likes = [{
    'userInfo': {
        'id': 121
    }
}]

hasSelfLike = any(like['userInfo']['id'] == user['id'] for like in likes)

print(hasSelfLike)
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user_info = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='userInfo')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def get_hasSelfLike(self):
        return self.likes.values_list('userInfo_id', 'userInfo__id') #returns always True


class Like(models.Model):
    task_id = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='likes', name='taskId')
    user_info = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='userInfo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `Task`s to return `Task`s with the user as like through an [**`F`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F

Task.objects.filter(
    likes__user_info=F('user_info')
)
```

or for a `Task`, you can check in a `Task` with:

```
def has_self_like(self):
    return self.user_info_id in self.likes.values_list('user_info_id', flat=True)
```

or through an `exists()`:

```
def has_self_like(self):
    return self.likes.filter(user_info_id=self.user_info_id).exists()
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `task_id`, instead of <s>`task`</s>.